# python __repr__

Tags: python

I have a class with `__str__` and `__repr__` defined:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, version):
        self.version = version
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.version

myObjs = {}
o = MyClass("1")
myObjs[o] = o
print myObjs
```

Which prints:

```
{1: 1}
```

How do I store the MyClass object as value to the dictionary instead of the string representation?
I could have added getVersion(), but just wanted to know if there is some more elegant way.

Thanks

Comment: You are storing the object...

Comment: `1` is what the class is being displayed as (that's what you told it to do). Run `type(myObjs.keys()[0])`.

Comment: Your `__repr__` should return `"MyClass('1')"` to be consistent with its original intent.

Comment: You say ``__str__()`` and ``__repr__()`` are defined, but only ``__repr__()`` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the dictionary is storing the object.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, version):
        self.version = version
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.version

myObjs = {}
o = MyClass("1")
myObjs[o] = o
print type(o)                                                                   
print o.__class__                                                               
print myObjs                                                                    
print type(myObjs[o])
```

Prints the following:

```
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
{1: 1}
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
```

The reason it prints this way is because the dictionary uses the `__repr__` of its keys and values for both its `__str__` and `__repr__` functions. You can always change your `__repr__` function though to make it less ambiguous with an integer:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '{0}({1})'.format(str(self.__class__.__name__), self.version)
```

Sample Output:

```
{MyClass(1): MyClass(1)}
```

Feel free to use whichever format that works best for you. I also changed your class to extend from object to make it a new style class (it brings classes and types together in the language and adds additional abilities to classes (such as decorators and the super function)). Otherwise:

```
print type(o)
```

Outputs

```
<type 'instance'>
```